# How to use position fixed to cover the full screen width?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am using `position: fixed` to fix the name of the website at the top of the page however in doing so the div boundary finishes as soon as the text in the div is completed. It's not covering the complete screen length:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 0%; position:fixed;">
  <div style="background-color: bisque; margin-top: 0%;  font-family: Copperplate, Papyrus, fantasy; color: black;  text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;
    <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ratnesh Nagi</a></h1> &nbsp;
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is how it's working with Fixed:
[image: This is how it's working with Fixed:]

This is how I want it to get fixed at the top:
[image: This is how I want it to get fixed at the top]

Comment: Might you be able to edit your question as a snippet to fully reproduce it here in the question with the minimal CSS and any libraries in play?

Comment: Are you open to an alternative to `position:fixed;` to accomplish what you describe?

Comment: Would you kindly accept one of the proposed answers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **100vw**

```css
nav{
  width = 100vw;
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 200vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100vw;
  /*  extra  */
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

.nagi{
  background-color: bisque;
  font-family: Copperplate, Papyrus, fantasy;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="nagi">
      &nbsp;
      <h1>
        <a href="#">Ratnesh Nagi</a>
      </h1> &nbsp;
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets (click on "Copy snippet to answer" when present, or use the icon that has `<>` in it) to provide a runnable example on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

### Set the `right` and `left` property to zero.

You can specify the horizontal position of *positioned* elements using `right` and `left` properties. See the snippet below:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 0%; position:fixed; right: 0; left:0;">
  <div style="background-color: bisque; margin-top: 0%;  font-family: Copperplate, Papyrus, fantasy; color: black;  text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;
    <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ratnesh Nagi</a></h1> &nbsp;
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` perhaps as an alternative with some other creative CSS

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  /* force this to full width*/
  align-self: stretch;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.navbar-content {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: bisque;
  font-family: Copperplate, Papyrus, fantasy;
  color: black;
  /* make it have a size without the &nbsp;*/
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.navbar-brand {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.new-thing {
  background-color: #bbdddd;
  /* force this to full width just for fun */
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="navbar-content">
      <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ratnesh Nagi</a></h1>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="new-thing">I am next in line</div>
</div>
```